# Defining Properties on a Javascript Object - Object.definedProperties displays empty object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have been following javascript design patterns and was implementing ES5 properties using the code found at this location.

https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript

**Test 1**

Use a function to define 3 properties

- Check the values are ok: SUCCESS
- Log the object to see if the data looks ok: SUCCESS

**Test 2**

Use Object.definedProperties to define 3 properties

- Check the values are ok: SUCCESS
- Log the object to see if the data looks ok: **FAIL**

**Test 1 Code**

```
it('should construct object with some single properites added using helper function', function (done) {

  var person = Object.create(Object.prototype);

  // Populate the object with properties
  pattern.defineProp(person, "car", "Delorean");
  pattern.defineProp(person, "dateOfBirth", "1981");
  pattern.defineProp(person, "hasBeard", false);

  console.log(person.car);
  console.log(person);
  console.log(typeof person);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(person));

  person.car.should.equal('Delorean');
  person.dateOfBirth.should.equal('1981');
  person.hasBeard.should.equal(false);

  // Produces
  // Delorean
  // { car: 'Delorean', dateOfBirth: '1981', hasBeard: false }
  // object
  // {"car":"Delorean","dateOfBirth":"1981","hasBeard":false}

  done();
});
```

**Test 2 Code**

```
it('should construct object with multiple properties using standard ES5 syntax', function (done) {

  var person = Object.create(Object.prototype);

  // Populate the object with properties
  Object.defineProperties(person, {

    "car": {
      value: "Delorean",
      writable: true
    },
    "dateOfBirth": {
      value: "1981",
      writable: true
    },
    "hasBeard": {
      value: false,
      writable: true
    }

  });
  console.log(person.car);
  console.log(person);
  console.log(typeof person);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(person));

  person.car.should.equal('Delorean');
  person.dateOfBirth.should.equal('1981');
  person.hasBeard.should.equal(false);

  // Produces
  // Delorean
  // {}
  // object
  // {}

  done();
});
```

**Define Prop Function**

```
exports.defineProp = function ( obj, key, value ){
  var config = {
    value: value,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  };
  Object.defineProperty( obj, key, config );
};
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Your configuration is different between your wrapped function and the plain `defineProperties`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you are using the standard `Object.defineProperties`, and omit the `enumerable` attribute, it will default to `false`. Your properties won't be displayed because they are not enumerable.

Comment: Thanks Bergi for the quick response, I altered my code and it worked correctly